# Hive - Explode in JOIN Condition

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to do explode on a column in a join condition.

```
select
t1.a,t2.b, t2.c
from table1 AS t1
join (select b,LATERAL VIEW explode(ABCD) AS c from person) AS t2 ON (t1.c=t2.c)
```

But, this query is failing. I suspect the subquery is not working as expected. 
In the subquery, I have selected two columns, one is column b and another is column c, which is an explode.

Is this way of writing subquery is correct? If wrong, how can I achieve this.

Error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Cannot do equality join on different types: string and map<bigint,array<string>>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting, can you post log?

also are you sure your column name is b in person table?

Comment: @Rijulsahu : Added the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE people(b int,abcd array<String> ); 

INSERT INTO people SELECT 1, ARRAY("bob", "alice", "tom") from dummy limit 1;
INSERT INTO people SELECT 2, ARRAY("john", "mike", "jack") from dummy limit 1;

create table table1(name string, salary int);
insert into table1 values("bob",1000);
insert into table1 values("alice",500);

hive> select b,c  from people LATERAL VIEW explode(ABCD) ep AS c;
OK
1       bob
1       alice
1       tom
2       john
2       mike
2       jack


hive> select
t1.salary,t2.b, t2.c
from table1 AS t1
join (select b,c  from people LATERAL VIEW explode(ABCD) ep AS c) AS t2 ON (t1.name=t2.c)

OK
1000    1       bob
500     1       alice
```

Comment: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Cannot do equality join on different types: string and map<bigint,array<string>>